# Wordpress and MySQL: trying to print data using PHP from user_meta custom field data

Tags: php, database, mysql

I have some custom user_meta fields in my MySQL database. The data is stored in my DB as follows:

the meta_key is called "paypal_user" and the info is stored in the meta_value column as:

O:11:"Paypal_User":9:{s:8:"duration";s:1:"1";s:13:"duration_type";s:1:"y";s:6:"amount";s:2:"30";s:8:"currency";s:3:"GBP";s:13:"last_pay_date";s:10:"2011-02-12";s:11:"expire_date";s:10:"2012-02-12";s:12:"account_type";s:7:"premium";s:10:"status_str";s:27:"Last payment was successful";s:12:"payment_type";s:12:"subscription";}

I need to print the "expire date" information on a webpage, as well as user_id and some form data s the user can print out a membership badge from the webpage.

How do I access that one particular part of the meta_data column?

Also, what do the numbers between each of the values in the meta_data column? I'm a newbie when it comes to using MySQL...

Thanks in advance.

Edit to add:

I'm posting my code as I can't seem to get it to work at all. Any pointers would be appreciated:

```
<?php
include_once('wp-config.php');
include_once('wp-load.php');
include_once('wp-includes/wp-db.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">

<!--    styling stuff -->

</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

<div id="top_badge">

    <?php 

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {

    global $user_ID;

 // Get the 'paypal_user' info for the user. Just fetch a single
// value, not an array.
$paypal_user = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'paypal_user', true);
$exp_date = $paypal_user->expire_date;
?>

    <div id="member_no_1"><?php echo '$user_ID' ?></div>
    <div id="member_lp_1">PR34 2PL</div>
    <div id="member_exp_1"><?php echo '$exp_date' ?></div>

</div>
<?php } ?>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: use `global $wpdp;` 
 https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: then use `unserialize` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unserialize.php

Answer (score 2):

That's a [serialized object variable](https://www.php.net/serialize). The numbers are string lengths, for example, where you see `s:8:"duration"`, notice that the word 'duration' is 8 characters long. You shouldn't have to worry about that, because WordPress will take care of it for you.

You can access the fields like so:

```
global $user_ID;

// Get the 'paypal_user' info for the user. Just fetch a single
// value, not an array.
$paypal_user = get_user_meta($user_ID, 'paypal_user', true);
$exp_date = $paypal_user->expire_date;
$paytype = $paypal_user->payment_type;
```

Comment: I've tried using that code and I'm getting this error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  get_user_meta(). I'm trying to access the database from outside Wordpress, if thats any help.

Comment: Ah, that would have been important to know. :) Assuming that you already fetched the data from the database into a variable called `$mymeta`, then do `$paypal_user = unserialize($mymeta);`

Comment: I've updated my question with my code as I am still having some issues - when I said it was outside Wordpress, what I meant was outwith the usual header info etc. I'm still within the same webspace. Sorry if I didn't make that clear.